# How to get sharedApplication in Swift on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I get instance of current UIApplication from View Controller in Swift?

I am getting `Use of unresolved identifier 'sharedApplication'` error with this code:

```
let app = sharedApplication as UIApplication
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

EDIT **Swift 4.x**

```
let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

If you're e.g. not in a ViewController, you must:

```
import UIKit
```

Perhaps try:

```
let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
```

EDIT (Swift 3):

It should be noted that in Swift 3, to accomplish this, you will want to access the `shared` property instead:

```
let app = UIApplication.shared
```

Comment: And btw. - don't forget to `import UIKit` if you're e.g. not in a ViewController

Comment: You are right, I got the same problem and it was the missing import.

Comment: Just to note, for Xcode 8 / Swift 3, it's just: UIApplication.shared

Answer (score 11):

You can do it by

```
let app =  UIApplication.sharedApplication()
```